# Phonegap : Floating bubble notification like facebook messenger in Phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w476b.jpg)
How to add floating bubble notification like this image in Phonegap.

Comment: what floating bubble?

Comment: Floating Bubble as used in facebook messenger chat app. By clicking on which user can come back to his App. Please see the attached image and if You have any idea please suggest for Phonegap.

Comment: Are you referring to the notification icon with the users image inside it?

Comment: yes exactly ,I have to do this in Phonegap.

Comment: I searched already that no plugin available for this but suggest another way possible to do this and please remove minus voting for my question.

Comment: please view my answer. Also, you can edit your question and provide more in depth details about what you have already done if you would like the downvote to be removed.

Comment: I have integrated FCM in my App and I want to show notification like this way with badge count.I have attached an image to explain what I want to ask.

Comment: The push notification plugin supports both `badges` and `icons`. And the icon variable is what you should be looking into. view my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is not "an out of box" plugin for what you are looking for. However you can either create your own plugin OR simply use the `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin and edit it to achieve what you are looking for.

The `phonegap-plugin-push` plugin has a support for icons. I assume you can further edit/develop this to do what you want.

Please view the push plugin:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#images

This plugin has some support for images and icons.

**EDIT:**

Reading further, it seems like that the push note plugin only supports the image/icon for Android devices.

But since you have provided a screenshot of Android device, I assume you are working on Android.

Take a note of this:

```
const push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "icon": "phonegap",
        "iconColor": "blue"
    },
```

*Where icon is the name of an .png image file in the Android res/drawable folder. For example: platforms/android/res/drawable/phonegap.png*